# ViewModel onCleared not called in RecyclerView

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

I have an adapter with code below. The problem is, that the onCleared()-Method of the ViewModel seems never being called for the ViewModels for the list items.
Is there a special method / flag that needs to be set to clear these ViewModels?

```
class BaseRecyclerViewViewModelAdapter(
        private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseRecyclerViewViewModelViewHolder>() {

    var items: List<BaseRecyclerViewItemViewModel> = emptyList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseRecyclerViewViewModelViewHolder {
        val binding: ViewDataBinding =
                DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), viewType, parent, false)
        return BaseRecyclerViewViewModelViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseRecyclerViewViewModelViewHolder, position: Int) {
        with(holder.binding) {
            setVariable(BR.viewModel, items[position])
            setLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = items[position].layoutId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And it won't be. According to the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):

> When the owner activity is finished, the framework calls the ViewModel
>   objects's onCleared() method so that it can clean up resources.

If you want to `clear` some things in the list - you should do it manually.

Comment: How would I do that? onCleared has protected access.

Comment: Create your own method, 'clear()' and call it from 'onCleared()' too, for example. It's up to you.